# How to centre the icon in this React-Native Expo Snack?

Tags: css, react-native, expo

I'm using [Expo](https://expo.io) and have a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/S1_IbDAq-) that uses [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements) and I can't seem to get the notifications icon exactly centred.  It appears to the left slightly.  I tried setting `marginRight: 0` but that doesn't help.

Can anyone fix this snack for me?

Comment: can you post your code snippet?

Comment: @MerajKhan It's linked in the question https://snack.expo.io/S1_IbDAq-

Comment: according to your code in this class ._19iubwk-o_O-_pnb0n0{ background-position: 1.5em center !important;} try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `marginRight: 0` on the icon's style instead of the button's style. react-native-elements' button icon attribute accepts a style object.
Replace your current `<Button />` with the one below and the icon should be centered.

```
<Button
  raised
  icon={{name: 'notifications', size: 90, style: {marginRight: 0}}}
  buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: '#ff4f00', borderRadius: 10}}
/>
```

Comment: In addition, here is a working Expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/HJncdPCq-